# Return position of value in a 2D array, Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, 2d, return

I'm tired.  This must be simple.  wood... for.... trees....

I'm trying to return the position of a specific value in a 2D array.

I have a double array [300][300].

All values contained in it are 0 apart from one which is 255.

How do I write a method to return the [i][j] location of 255?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these values sorted?  If so, there are `O(log n)` (completely sorted) or `O(n log n)` (only rows or columns sorted) versions.  Otherwise, you're stuck with `O(n^2)`, as has been provided.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse what do these O things mean. They make no sense to me and I thus do not understand their value

Comment: @JohnnyCoder - it's called [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  It's a simple measure of the expected number of steps required to do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate over all the elements until you find the one that is `255`:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 300; ++i ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 300; ++j ) {
        if ( array[i][j] == 255 ) {
            // Found the correct i,j - print them or return them or whatever
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shakedown and thanks so much for your help.  I had reached this point but was having trouble returning both the integers.  i.e. if [150][200] held 255 how would I return those two integers to then use elsewhere?  Once I've got the location I then need to use these two as the first two locations in a 3D array ([150][200][75]).  /**Can you tell I'm a newb?**/

Comment: @OliverBurdekin: If you want to return them you'd have to put them into an array or make an object that has both of them in it. Or, you could set some class variables internally in that method (and not return anything), though I don't like this. Another option is to leave those i,j variables inside that method and just pass them along to another method that will then use those for further indexing.

Comment: @OliverBurdekin Regarding how to return the pair of numbers, the column and row numbers of the found cell, in Java 16 defining your own class has become easier, where the main purpose of the class is to communicate data transparently and immutably: [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395): `public record Cell ( int column , int row ) {}`. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. So your inner `for` loop would say: `return new Cell( j , i ) ;`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public int[] get255() {
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < (array[i].length/2)+1; j++)
      if(array[i][j] == 255)
        return new int[] {i,j};
      else if(array[j][i] == 255) //This just slightly increases efficiency
        return new int[] {j,i};
  return null; //If not found, return null
}
```

This is possibly the fastest, though. It checks starting in each corner, progressively working inward to the center, horizontally first, then vertically:

```
public int[] get255() {
  for(int i = 0; i < (array.length/2)+1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < (array[i].length/2)+1; j++)
      // Check the top-left
      if(array[i][j] == 255)
        return new int[] {i,j};

      // Check the bottom-left
      else if(array[array.length-i][j] == 255)
        return new int[] {array.length-i,j};

      // Check the top-right
      else if(array[i][array[i].length-j] == 255)
        return new int[] {i,array[i].length-j};

      // Check the bottom-right
      else if(array[array.length-i][array[i].length-j])
        return new int[] {array.length-i, array[i].length-j};

  return null; //If not found, return null
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this check every element twice if 255 isn't in the array?

Comment: yes, but if you can assume that 255 will be in the array, it has around a 25% reduction in time at best.

Comment: Well, you could just iterate `i=0..length/2` and `j=0..length/2` instead to prevent double-checking. (Might be off-by-one)

Comment: @skyuzo don't know why I forgot about that, added now. Also added a safety with `.length/2+1`. `i` has to go through the entire length, though.

Comment: This might not actually be more efficient though. You're still making the same number of comparisons as Shakedown's answer (n^2).

Comment: `n^2` is worst-case. The average case is still faster since it checks both sides before re-iterating. The most efficient may include two more checks (adding in as a second code sample).

Comment: On average, it iterates fewer times. I'm saying that it makes the same number of comparisons, given random data. If 255 tends to occur more often on the "ends" of the array, then this will be more efficient. However, if 255 tends to occur more in the middle of the array, then Shakedown's answer will make half as many comparisons as your algorithm. So, I guess that in order to optimize this algorithm, we'll need to know some more information about the data set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5637/discussion-between-jon-and-skyuzo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search for each column.

Use **for** loop to iterate over each column as it is an 2d array.

Once you get all the rows from the specific column you are iterating ( which would be another array), do a binary search on them.

**Conditions Apply:**
 1. If the array is sorted . 
 2. If you are sure that only one element is there in each column. ( No duplicates).
 3. If there are duplicates in the rows( do linear search) .

I hope it helps. Please feel free to ask if still in doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

For any size of Array, you have put to the size first, though I have used a scanner to input value directly, you can bring it from another method also, I am learning so if I am wrong please correct me. On your case value will be 255 instead of 1.

```
public class MagicSquareOwn {



    public static int[] findValueByElement(int n) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] squareMatrix = new int[n][n];


    int[] position = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                squareMatrix[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                if (squareMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
                     position= new int[] { i, j };
                     System.out.println("position is:" + Arrays.toString(position));
                }
            }
        }

        return position;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inputOfMatrixNo = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = inputOfMatrixNo.nextInt();
        MagicSquareOwn.findValueByElement(n);

    }

}
```